# ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4 requires ruby-debug-base19?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I have switched to ruby 2.0.0, rails 4 from rails 3, when i run the command `bundle update rails` i get this error

```
An error occurred while installing ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ruby-debug-base19 -v '0.11.25'` succeeds before bundling.
```

But when run gem install ruby-debug-base19 -v '0.11.25' i got that error:

```
   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-base19:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/sunloverz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
    checking for vm_core.h... no
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:39:in `create_makefile_with_core': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:39:in `create_makefile_with_core': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
    checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
    checking for vm_core.h... no
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
    libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
    need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/sunloverz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
        --with-ruby-dir
        --without-ruby-dir
        --with-ruby-include
        --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
        --with-ruby-lib
        --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in read': Looking for http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz and all I got was a 404! (URI::NotFoundError)
```

Answer (score 2):

Substitute `ruby-debug-base19` in your Gemfile with a Ruby 2.0 compatible debugger such as `byebug` and run the command again.

Comment: Really? `ruby-debug-base19` is not in your Gemfile anymore and still tries to install it?

Comment: Post your Gemfile, or better, connect to the chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-on-rails

Comment: I usually advice to upgrade your debugger, but you can downgrade your ruby as well, of course. Happy that you got that fixed.